# Simple Linked List in C : memory Access Error

Tags: c, data-structures

```
#include "List.h"

typedef int element;                                
typedef struct _ListNode //form of node
{
    element data;                                       
    struct ListNode *link;
}   ListNode;


ListNode *header = NULL; //make header in global variable
int num_node = 0; //counting number of nodes

int AppendNode(const ListNode item);
void DisplayItem(void); 
int InsertNode(const int pos, const ListNode item);


int AppendNode(const ListNode item)                     
{
    ListNode *current, *new_item = NULL;
    new_item = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    if (new_item == NULL)   return 0;

    new_item->data = item.data;                     
    new_item->link = NULL;                              

    if (header == NULL)                         
        header = new_item;                      
    else{                                   
        current = header;                       
        while (current->link != NULL)                   
        {
            current = current->link;                    
            current->link = new_item;                   
        }
    }
    num_node++;                                         
    return 1;                                           
}


void DisplayItem(void) //print all the nodes
{
    ListNode *current = NULL;
    current = header;   
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", current->data); //MEMORY ACCESS PROBLEM
        current = current->link;
    }
}

int InsertNode(const int position, const ListNode item)
{
    ListNode *current = NULL;
    ListNode *new_item = NULL;
    new_item = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    if (new_item == NULL)   return 0;

    if (position == 1)
    {
        new_item->link = header;
        header = new_item;
        num_node++;
    }
    else if((1 < position) && (position < num_node))
    {
        int current_position = 0;       
        current = header;           
        while (current_position != (position - 1))
        {
            current = current->link;
            current_position++;
        }
        new_item->link = current->link;
        current->link = new_item;
        num_node++;
    }
    else return 0;                                  
}

int main(void)
{
    ListNode node1; node1.data = 10;    
    DisplayItem();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to make simple linked list program. but it doesn't work because of Memory Access Problem.
Also, I make two more nodes, but it doesn't be appended except node 1.
I wanted to use Call-by-Reference. and all function should be make result 0, 1.

```
0 - fail.
1 - success.
```

It looks like uncomfortable but... How could I make this work?

Comment: I suggest you step through your code line by line in a debugger. There are a few pieces of code that are very wrong. For example the loop in `AppendNode`. I suggest you take a very much closer look at it.

Comment: In while loop you should temporary assing `current = current->next` only and once you are out of while loop, assign `current->link = new_item`. `while (current->link != NULL) { current = current->link; } current->link = new_item;` would be correct. This is point @Someprogrammerdude mentioned.

Comment: You have not created the link list. Your `*header` is always NULL.

Comment: `struct ListNode *link;` --> `struct _ListNode *link;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see your simple mistake below with my comment and try with my correction below:-

```
typedef struct _ListNode //form of node
{
    element data;                                       
    struct ListNode *link;/* here it should be _ListNode */
}   ListNode;
```

now see your below method where you did the mistake

```
int AppendNode(const ListNode item)                     
{
    ListNode *current, *new_item = NULL;
    new_item = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    if (new_item == NULL)   return 0;

    new_item->data = item.data;                     
    new_item->link = NULL;                              

    if (header == NULL)                         
        header = new_item;                      
    else{                                   
        current = header;                       
        while (current->link != NULL) 
        /* here in the above while statement current->link always NULL because it is pointing to the first node and first->next == NULL. Hence this while loop will never execute and link list will not be created because you have assign the new node inside this while loop. Move the code out side of this loop */               
        {
            current = current->link;                    
            current->link = new_item;                   
        }
    }
```

correct while loop should be

```
       while (current->link != NULL) 
        {
            current = current->link;                                  
        }
          current->link = new_item; /* this line of code should be out side of while loop */
    num_node++;                                         
    return 1;                                           
 }

Just correct the while loop like above in function AppendNode as well.
Now it will work fine
```

Comment: Sorry for late comment. Not 100%, but it similarly worked! Thanks!